# How to read and write an NSString with UTF8N?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

How to read and write an NSString with UTF8N? I use this to load a UTF-8 file and it seems to work with UTF-8N.

`NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:destPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];`

The problem is when I save the file with

`[string writeToFile:tempFile atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];`

the file is not readable in a normal text editor on the computer. I can still read the file as a UTF-8 file though.

What am I missing?

Comment: And what is the text editor telling you when you try to open the file?

Comment: Try opening your original file and the file your program wrote in a hex editor and compare the raw byte values. That should give you an idea what’s going on. Could maybe be an issue with a byte order mark?

Comment: @Wevah nothing. The editors open the file but the text is just random characters and symbols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bunch of guess and check found `NSShiftJISStringEncoding` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the string to file without providing any encoding

```
        [string writeToFile:tempFile atomically:YES];
```

Comment: That method is deprecated, but I suppose it could be useful in tracking down where the error is.

Comment: That is where I started, but its worth a try I guess.